# Is there an antonym of the word technocrat in English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, expressions

Yesterday night in a TV show, the Chief Reporter who was talking about our new technocrats government asked mockingly and rhetorically:

> What is the technocrat's antonym? Perhaps "pafarist"...

This is actually not a word in my language, it's an invented one meaning "beyond (out of) everything or good at nothing", but its slang use is very widely spread.

I wonder: Is there an antonym of the word technocrat in English? I'm thinking of "Jack of all trades, master of none", but I'm not sure if it would fit well.

Comment: Outside of the political context, I would suggest technophobe or possibly [Luddite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luddite).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*technocrat* basically means](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/technocrat) *an ​expert in ​science or ​technology who has a lot of ​power in or ​influence with the ​government or ​industry*. I referred a few other dictionaries and everywhere I found that 'expert in technology/science' **and** 'influence' or 'high position' in government are *two* things necessary to explain the word. So, having an antonym that is opposite to **both** of those meanings may not be possible.

In such a trap, I'd simply use the suffix ***'non-'***.

> non-technocrat

As I see some examples from the news sites and books, the word ['non-technocrat' is not strange](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/obituaries/finance-obituaries/9172100/Sir-George-Blunden.html) to use.

Comment: Thanks, very simple indeed. What about anarchist, can it ever be an antonym of the word in question?

Comment: No, it's completely different. Does not involve 'technology/science' and top of all, is not linked with any influence.